# Pandas Sort Values and Ignore NaN values if condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following pandas Dataframe inside a function that I must not change it:

```py
self.df =
id Col2 
1    nan
2    5  
3    3
```

Now I have this function:

```
def order_by_col2(self, index_list, keep_nan_values=False):
```

where I need to keep or drop the NaN values depending on the flag `keep_nan_values` after sorting them by the column `col2`.
I have as input the list of indexes and I want to return them ordered.

At the moment I have something like this:

```
return list(self.df.loc[index_list]
              .sort_values(by=['Col2'], na_position='last')
              .index)
```

but I really can't make the flag `keep_nan_values`, when False, working.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I need by adding an apply function

I actually needed to import `numpy.isnan()` function. If there any better solution let me know!

```py
return list(self.df.loc[index_list]
              .loc[df.loc[index_list]['Col2'].apply(
                  lambda x: True if keep_nan_values else not np.isnan(x))]
              .sort_values(by=['Col2'], na_position='last')
              .index)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [dropna()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method:

```py
def order_by_col2(df, index_list, keep_nan_values=False):
    if not keep_nan_values:
        df = df.dropna(subset=index_list)
    ...
    return list(df.loc[index_list]
              .sort_values(by=['Col2'], na_position='last')
              .index)
```

Comment: I'm not able to change the dataframe, so I can't simply drop their NaN values :S I perhaps could copy the dataframe, but my dataframe takes already a lot of memory

Comment: `dropna` will return a copy without specifying `inplace=True` flag. You can also place dropna after the `sort_values` call (it also creates a copy)